# Should there be a 'frame-challenge' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Understanding that there has been discussions about frame challenges in the past, notably in [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7097/a-proposal-for-helping-users-understand-frame-challenges) and [this other question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/help-controlling-a-misguided-frame-challenge-answer-which-has-created-a-debate) (plus certain others), is there any disputable reason why there is not a tag for designating frame challenges, given that such questions exist?

Is it because it can too open-ended? Too controversial? Too much of a 'what-if' scenario? Not enough to intrinsically describe a question?

Comment: All the downvoting for people asking questions (especially in the Meta) seems so petty. This seems like a reasonable thing to ask, even if people don't agree with it.

Comment: @DWKraus voting on meta is supposed to signify agreement/disagreement with the premise. It's a shorthand to answering with a "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, while I can figure one being seen as an expert in biology, hard-science or alternative heart, what would exactly an expert in frame challenge be?

Second but not less important, what would a frame challenge question be? Frame challenge can be a type of answer, but not an intrinsic content of the question. And if you are asking a question with the sole purpose of challenging its frame you are opening up an endless discussion, not giving a closed problem. For that type of discussion SE is not the right place.

Answer (score 3):

Frame challenges are not an element of world building. If you wish to test whether your world (or some rule or context in it) makes sense, then the appropriate tag is [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check). That one works even if your world is not realistic in terms of our own world, i.e.: you want a world where wormholes are an everyday thing, and you wish to know whether that would break causality because wormholes allow for FTL. You can tag it with [physics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics), and you can also tag with [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check).